# What TextMate theme is this?

Tags: themes, textmate

Can anyone tell me what syntax highlighting theme is in use here?

http://jamierumbelow.net/images/code.png

Jamie Rumbelow and Elliot Haughin both seem to use it. It looks really nice and I have asked both of them but helpfully, they don't answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this one : [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/about)

Comment: Again thanks for the input. I've got idleFingers and while it is the closest match I have found, it isn't quite the same. Thank you though.

Comment: I've just revisited this question - turns out it is that theme! Sorry for the confusion. And what a great theme it is! All the best. Have marked this as the Answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks kind of like [this one](http://blog.infinitered.com/entries/show/2), typically called the "last TextMate theme you'll need." I use it myself, and like it quite a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I don't think it is. :(